# Direct link to video in Google Plus?

Tags: google-plus

Anyone have any idea if it is possible to link directly to a video that is posted in a Google Plus/Picasa gallery?

You can link directly to a photo by right clicking in IE and copying the URL of the photo but I don't see an obvious way to do it with video.

Answer (score 1):

When in the video, hit share and select "copy link".
If it's not listed you cannot do that for that video.